# Counting files in if loop

Tags: powershell

How do you count how many files have entered an if statement in powershell?
Here is what i have

```
 foreach($tiff in $tiffs2){

        if($tiff.FullName.Substring($tiff.FullName.length-12,4) -eq $pattern){




           $tiff = $tiff.Name.split('.')[0]

              cd C:\Users\xxxxxxx\Desktop\Nconvert\XnView 
              #./nconvert -help > nchelp.txt 
              .\nconvert.exe -out pdf -c 3 -multi -n 1 $pages 1 -o "$output\$tiff.pdf" "$InputLocation\*.tif"


        }

    }
}
```

How do i count how many files go into that if statement?

Comment: By incrementing a counter with each iteration, if I am not totally mistaken...

Comment: how exactly would i go about writing that out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using a counter, of course. :-)

```
$ctr = 0
foreach($tiff in $tiffs2)
{
    if($tiff.FullName.Substring($tiff.FullName.length-12,4) -eq $pattern)
    {
        $ctr++
        $tiff = $tiff.Name.split('.')[0]

        cd C:\Users\xxxxxxx\Desktop\Nconvert\XnView 
        #./nconvert -help > nchelp.txt 
        .\nconvert.exe -out pdf -c 3 -multi -n 1 $pages 1 -o "$output\$tiff.pdf" "$InputLocation\*.tif"
    }
}
```